# How are DigitalOcean's one-click apps maintained?

Tags: digital-ocean

DigitalOcean has a lot of [one-click apps](https://www.digitalocean.com/features/one-click-apps/) available. They help you create a droplet with pre-installed software. But I haven't found any technical documentation on them.

Specifically:

- who maintains those apps? (Can the community help upgrade them, for instance?)
- what's the workflow of creating such an application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a Community Manager at DigitalOcean and our team maintains these images.  While we do sometimes work directly with open source projects to build and maintain images generally these are build completely in-house. We choose images to build based on feedback on our [uservoice](http://do.co/uvoice).

As for the workflow, these images are created using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) scripts.  We will create a new droplet using a base image (Usually the latest Ubuntu LTS release) and use fabric to configure the droplet.  A snapshot is then created and tested.  The snapshot image is then converted to a public image by way of some database changes and is then available in the control panel.

A user can use this same procedure to create custom snapshots on their account.

Comment: Does that mean existing apps get upgraded eventually or do you wait for customer input?

Comment: The available application images are updated regularly.  It is still always recommended to do an apt-get upgrade on a new one-click droplet to ensure all software is up to date.

Comment: I am curious if you have those open sourced, or if one could contribute a new OCA